# Pop3 multiprocess, process one message, once time

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, pop3, distributed-computing

I'm using .NET POP3, .net 3.5, vs 2008.

I have a windows service installed in several machines. Each machine (windows service installed in machine) access to the same inbox POP3 (the same account) for process messages.

Using multi-threading, multiple scripts running at the same time is actually ideal, is it possible using the component POP3 ??

Each message must be process once time, for any machine (only one machine must process the message).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that POP3 has no concept of locking jobs/messages, so multiple clients logging into the same account at the same time will all get the same set of messages.

I had to solve a similar problem however, and this is how I achieved it. Firstly I used IMAP rather than POP3. Each client then registers a folder under the main inbox. I then have one master node that manages the INBOX root folder. All other nodes request a job from the master node which performs a simple move of the job from the root inbox to the requesting nodes folder. The node can then extract the job directly from its private folder without needing to worry about interference from other nodes.

If you were wondering on why there needs to be a master node it is because IMAP does not have an atomic move operation, but is rather a copy then delete two phase operation. This means that to prevent any sort of concurrency issues you can still really only have one thread/process accessing the INBOX folder.

Answer (score 1):

[I did this myself a couple of years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913487/email-monitor-synchronization).

I ended up storing the messages' UIDs in a shared SQL Server table with UNIQUE constraint.
Before processing each message, add it to the table.
If you get an exception, a different machine already grabbed it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, although horribly inefficient. Because POP3 is polled, you'd also introduce a lot latency. Why would you want to distribute your workload like this? What are you really trying to solve?

Comment: how is it possible ? any sample ? My company wants do this. Which will be the better option then ??